# Test multiple Haxe target languages with a single script

Tags: haxe

In Haxe, is there any script or command that can automatically run a Haxe program in multiple target languages? I'd like to write a script that does the following:

1) Compile Haxe source code to JavaScript, C++, PHP, and Java.

2) Display the output of the Haxe program in each target language.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14409869/ensure-that-a-haxe-program-will-run-on-all-platforms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with normal hxml,  and a special js runtime that lets you output to the terminal.  I'm using [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/), but other environments like node.js are possible.

Note that I need to add append a specific exit command in order for phantomjs to exit properly.  See the phantomjs docs for more details. You'll also need to install hxjava and hxcpp from haxelib.

I'm using `--next` here to do multiple compilations in one pass.  You can easily break this up into multiple hxml files, and manage it via a makefile, etc.

```
-main Main  
-php php                                                                        
-cmd echo "PHP:"                                                                
-cmd php php/index.php                                                          
-cmd echo "\n"                                                                  

--next                                                                          
-main Main                                                                      
-js bin/Main.js                                                                 
-cmd echo "phantom.exit();" >> bin/Main.js                                      
-cmd echo "JS:"                                                                 
-cmd phantomjs bin/Main.js                                                      
-cmd echo "\n"                                                                  

--next                                                                          
-main Main                                                                      
-cpp cpp                                                                        
-cmd echo "CPP:"                                                                
-cmd ./cpp/Main                                                                 
-cmd echo "\n"                                                                  

--next                                                                          
-main Main                                                                      
-java java                                                                      
-cmd echo "JAVA:"                                                               
-cmd java -jar java/java.jar                                                    
-cmd echo "\n"
```

Comment: Which operating system(s) is this script intended to run on?

Comment: This should work on typical unix systems.  For windows you'd have to change the directory slashes.  "echo" and the ">>" operator should work on most platforms.